# Unable to follow links, scrapy callback isn't working properly

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was having an easy time with scrapy until I began trying to incorporate a second parsing method in my spider to handle links. I keep getting the following error when I try to run it:

**"parse_dir_contents() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'"**

Not sure why this is the case. I've followed the basic model presented in the official scrapy documentation.

Here's my code:

```
import scrapy
from bloombergspider.items import ArticleItem


class BloombergSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bloomberg"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.bloomberg.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.bloomberg.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "articles")]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents, dont_filter="true")

    @staticmethod
    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//h1'):
            self.logger.info("parse dir contents")
            item = ArticleItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath(".//span/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: why did you make the `parse_dir_contents()` static?

Comment: Well it works when I remove the static tag, the IDE had suggested making it static before but I guess that was no longer the case